# newbie question - firebase svelte-infinite-loading - unable to read new data from firestore

Tags: firebase, svelte-3

I'm trying to load db content on scroll down, but i'm getting errors because i don't know how to read correctly the data. Error shows that there is no data.hits, is undefined. What that means?

I used this sample: [svelte-infinite-loading sample](https://svelte.dev/repl/c053fb0b13154b07a503ac04e0cb2c66?version=3.32.3) and tried to apply to work with firebase, but I don't know how to read the console.log(data), hits is undefined, but should it be?

Could someone help me?

ContentBlocks.svelte

```
<script>
import InfiniteLoading from "svelte-infinite-loading";

let page = 1;


function fetchData({ detail: { loaded, complete } }) {
        const response = db
            .collection("todos")
            .orderBy("created", "desc")
            .startAfter(page*5)
            .limit(5);
        response.get().then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            if (data.hits.length) {
                 page += 1;
                 list = [...list, ...data.hits];
                 loaded();
             } else {
                 complete();
             }
        });
    }
</script>

<Box>
    <InfiniteLoading on:infinite={fetchData} />
</Box>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

is use async / await but that will still help you (also, your list variable is not declared anywhere we can see):

```
const results = await queryObj.get(); // queryObj == your response constant
if (results.docs) {
  list.concat(results.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
}
```

doc is here, with another solution to that problem : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection